# Add Product Variant - 404 Error

Tags: vb.net, shopify

I am developing a VB.NET application to interact with our new Shopify store. I am in the process of automating product additions/updates/removal based on data in our Oracle database.

Basically the application creates a new Shopify part for a pattern, then creates product variants for each sku in that pattern. It does this by POSTing and PUTing requests using the `HttpWebRequest` class. This was working great through yesterday afternoon, now today for some reason it's failing on the product variant creation/update with a 404 - Not Found error code.

The product add request JSON is below. This works perfectly, it creates the part on Shopify which I can then see through the admin panel. This is POSTed to the URL "https://key:password@bath-and-window-direct.myshopify.com/admin/products.json" (where key and password are replaced with our credentials)

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": 0,
        "body_html": "A classic combination of embroidery and cut work form the flowing border, creating your own seaside retreat. ",
        "title": "Seabreeze Sand",
        "vendor": "SKL",
        "product_type": "",
        "published_scope": "global",
        "tags": "J71227",
        "variants": null,
        "options": null,
        "images": [{
            "id": 0,
            "product_id": 0,
            "position": 1,
            "src": "http:\/\/i320.photobucket.com\/albums\/nn353\/fkhphoto\/J71227main.jpg",
            "variant_ids": null
        }],
        "image": null
    }
}
```

This is the JSON reply I'm receiving after this call, and I can also see the part added in the Shopify admin panel:

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": 7874734983,
        "title": "Seabreeze Sand",
        "body_html": "A classic combination of embroidery and cut work form the flowing border, creating your own seaside retreat. ",
        "vendor": "SKL",
        "product_type": "",
        "created_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
        "handle": "seabreeze-sand",
        "updated_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
        "published_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
        "template_suffix": null,
        "published_scope": "global",
        "tags": "J71227",
        "variants": [{
            "id": 24925005383,
            "product_id": 7874734983,
            "title": "Default Title",
            "price": "0.00",
            "sku": "",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": 0,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": null,
            "option1": "Default Title",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
            "taxable": true,
            "barcode": null,
            "image_id": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 1,
            "weight": 0.0,
            "weight_unit": "lb",
            "old_inventory_quantity": 1,
            "requires_shipping": true
        }],
        "options": [{
            "id": 9404426823,
            "product_id": 7874734983,
            "name": "Title",
            "position": 1,
            "values": ["Default Title"]
        }],
        "images": [{
            "id": 16242879303,
            "product_id": 7874734983,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1363/2407/products/J71227main.jpg?v=1468507436",
            "variant_ids": []
        }],
        "image": {
            "id": 16242879303,
            "product_id": 7874734983,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
            "updated_at": "2016-07-14T10:43:56-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1363/2407/products/J71227main.jpg?v=1468507436",
            "variant_ids": []
        }
    }
}
```

Immediately after that, I'm POSTing the following JSON to add a product variant to this newly created part, to the URL "https://key:password@bath-and-window-direct.myshopify.com/admin/products/7874734983/variants.json". This is the call that returns a 404 - Not Found error through the `HttpWebRequest` class.

```
{
    "variant": {
        "id": 0,
        "product_id": 7874734983,
        "title": "Seabreeze Tier Curtain in Sand",
        "price": "11.99",
        "sku": "J7122700013V09",
        "compare_at_price": "0.00",
        "position": 0,
        "grams": 0,
        "option1": "57X13 ROD POCKET VAL",
        "option2": null,
        "option3": null,
        "taxable": true,
        "barcode": "036326422417",
        "weight": 0,
        "weight_unit": "lb",
        "inventory_quantity": 550,
        "old_inventory_quantity": 550,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "image_id": null,
        "metafields": [{
            "id": 0,
            "key": "point1",
            "value": "57 x 13 Valance",
            "value_type": "string",
            "namespace": "J7122700013V09"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "key": "point2",
            "value": "To achieve the look in the photo, use one valance and one tier pair.",
            "value_type": "string",
            "namespace": "J7122700013V09"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "key": "point3",
            "value": "Feels like you are in your own beach cottage.",
            "value_type": "string",
            "namespace": "J7122700013V09"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "key": "point4",
            "value": "100% Polyester.",
            "value_type": "string",
            "namespace": "J7122700013V09"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "key": "point5",
            "value": " ",
            "value_type": "string",
            "namespace": "J7122700013V09"
        }]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The URLs, when copied into a web browser, work perfectly fine...I can see all the JSON of the current data. But when attempting to add the variant, I'm getting the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving out the `"id": 0` properties — both from the variant and from the metafields. Shopify will determine the IDs automatically.

Comment: This worked for me, although I only had to remove the `"id": 0` property from the metafields for some reason. I have been sending the same thing on products, product variants, product images, and orders with no issue, but leaving it on the metafield throws a 404 Not Found error, which seems inappropriate. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `id` is to be used only when you are updating something. `variants/<id>.json` or `metafields/<id>.json`